# Yii2 Client Side Form Validation Issue

Tags: php, yii2

I have a form that combines fields from multiple models. The client side validations (ie validateOnChange/validateOnSubmit) work for all but one model. I have searched my code to see if I did any thing different with the offending model which is causing this issue but I found everything to be fine.

Has anyone experienced a similar challenge? What are the possible causes and how can I go about fixing  them?

Comment: Is it really that hard to share sine useful information, such as a piece of code? Possible causes range from your screwing things up to a bug in the framework. We'll never know unless you show an example depicting the issue...

Comment: @W.B. sorry for the terse post. I later discovered it was a bug in the framework. I fixed it and sent a pull request already. The culprit is the way the clientOptions are added to the form in ActiveField::begin. The client options are indexed by the attribute name, this causes some attributes client options to be overwritten if other models added after it have field with the same attribute name. My fix indexed the forms client option by the input id ie Html::getInputId($model, $attribute)